# Google maps is not working on live but working in local

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

Html Code

`<div class="panel-body">`

`<div id="map_canvas" style="position: relative;width: 1050px;top: 100%;bottom: 0;height: 500px;"></div>`

`</div>`

Jquery

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=**********&callback=initMap

```
function initMap() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
   zoom: 4,
   center: {lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629}
});
 setMarkers(map);
}
var beaches = [

            ['India', 20.5937, 78.9629, 1],
           ];

    function setMarkers(map) {
        var image = {
            url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
        };
        var shape = {
            coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
            type: 'poly'
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
            var beach = beaches[i];
            console.log(beach);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                shape: shape,
                title: beach[0],
                zIndex: beach[3]
            });
        }
    }
```

here is the code of the google maps.

The problem is in the production but it is working fine in local.

The error is as follows for production :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.vg (js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:90)
    at new Ag (js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:92)
    at initMap (location:222)
    at js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:98
    at js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:56
    at Object._.Mc (js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:53)
    at Xc (js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:56)
    at js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:135
    at Object.google.maps.Load (js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:21)
    at js?key=AIzaSyDSGjhKsJgMAQmzn1E5UTGQvKtNLKKqMNo&callback=initMap:134
```

Comment: have you added your production domain to allowed domains while creating api key? You have to do it to get it working on live domains.

Comment: Did you setup a Google Maps API key with an IP restriction?

Comment: Thanks for update !!! Let me check with that...

Comment: @AshokkumarM.Prajapati Can you please tell from where i have to do it?

Comment: @AncientAnt No i didn't set any restriction.

Comment: I have created the api key from my gmail id and enable it and paste.

Comment: The error implies that you don't have the `<div>` with id="map_canvas" on your new domain.